# Ionic 2 Syntax Error While Compiling TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

While following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AMbEXSBE-Q) I get to the point where I am getting a syntax error while compiling my typescript code.

Here is the error:

> /app/pages/list/list.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   /focus/projects/ionic-todo/app/pages/list/list.js: Unexpected token
>   (10:17)    8 |     9 | export class ListPage {
>
> > 10 |   constructor(nav: NavController){
> >          |                  ^   11 |     this.nav = nav;   12 |    13 |     this.items = [

As you can see, it seems to think there is something wrong with the colon. However if you remove the colon then you get a similar error where the space is instead.

Here is the full code:

```js
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AddItemPage} from '../add-item/add-item';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/list/list.html'
})

export class ListPage {
  constructor(nav: NavController){
    this.nav = nav;

    this.items = [
      {'title': 'hi', 'description': 'hello'},
      {'title': 'sadf', 'description': 'asdfasdf'},
      {'title': 'asd', 'description': 'asdf'}
    ];
  }

  addItem()
  {
    this.nav.push(AddItemPage, {ListPage: this});
  }
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: You have this error when loading your module? I mean when executing your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error let me think that you try to execute directly your TypeScript code without having compiled (preprocessing) or transpiled it on the fly.

I think that your code should be ES6 only. In fact, with ES6, you have the class support but not type support (in constructor / method for example).

I had a look at Ionic2 generator templates and they seem to be ES6. See this link:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tabs/tree/master/www

You could adapt your code like this:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AddItemPage} from '../add-item/add-item';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/list/list.html'
})

export class ListPage {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }

  constructor(nav){
    this.nav = nav;

    this.items = [
      {'title': 'hi', 'description': 'hello'},
      {'title': 'sadf', 'description': 'asdfasdf'},
      {'title': 'asd', 'description': 'asdf'}
    ];
  }

  addItem()
  {
    this.nav.push(AddItemPage, {ListPage: this});
  }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm afraid I still don't understand why it worked for the man in the tutorial but I am just happy to have found a solution.

Comment: There is a better way to solve it than changing the code?
The link provided is not really explicative.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing in .js file you will have to give the static block i.e.

```
static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController]];
  }
```

to get the type of `nav`, that is inside the contructor parameter.

but in .ts file, you need not define the static block, you can simply define it inside the constructor like :

```
constructor (nav : NavController) {}
```

you can think of it as `nav` is a variable and `NavController` is the type.

That is the reason why you were getting the error. You were using typescript(.ts) syntax in javascript(.js) file.

So next time while you are watching a tutorial try to see if the tutor is working with .js file or .ts file :-)

Hope it helps.